# Designing a DFA binary string with exactly 2 occurrences of 010?

Tags: finite-automata

hi I'm having difficulty in Designing a DFA binary string with exactly 2 occurrences of 010?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that.

Comment: As you said the question is already asked before where can I find the solution?

Comment: Here's a sketch of how you could do it. (1) make a DFA that accepts all strings with exactly one instance of $\mathtt{010}$. You can do it with three states. (2) appropriately join two copies of your machine to make a DFA that accepts all strings with exactly two instances of $\mathtt{010}$. (3) make another machine that rejects any string containing $\mathtt{010}$ and appropriately join that to the one you made in step (3).